# c# ms chart : how do i count how many data points i have?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

is it possible to count how many data points i have ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For example, to get the number of points in the first series:

```
int numPoints = chart1.Series[0].Points.Count;
```